# Is it possible to find out which software/parameters are opened pressing some hotkey?

Tags: windows-7, windows, logging, hotkeys

I have some hotkey that I press when I do some actions (to open Software, and so on).

Is it possible to monitor these actions? Just to see which file and parameters are called pressing this key...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the application in question implements its hotkey functionality via the `RegisterHotKey` Windows API, then you can capture the `WM_HOTKEY` Window Message using [Spy++](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html).

Locate the Window(s) for your application, right-click and select "Messages." This will begin listing all window messages sent to the window. Look for the `WM_HOTKEY` (or maybe `WM_KEYUP/DOWN` or even `unknown`) message:

[image: Screenshot of a captured WM_HOTKEY message]

This is not fool-proof, though, as there are other ways to implement hotkeys.

Comment: What I'd like to do is get which file/parameter is called after WINLOGO+ALT+INVIO (which open windows media center). Can I do this with Spy++? Can't right-click on WMC...

Comment: Oh...now I see what do you mean as "right click". Well, tried to find Windows Media Center window, but can't find it. Do you know where can I catch it?

Comment: P.S. I don't want to capture hotkey combination, I want to understand on which file+attribute the hotkey work...

Comment: With the Find Tool I found eHome FlipEx Host Window - 000A02BE! Damn, they are not ordered...its a shame search it...